# Transform List of object to a Map in java

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have a list of item `List<Item> resultBl` like below :

```
id  = 18003  amount = 128 nameType = SUBMITTED
id  = 18189 amount = 95 nameType = SUBMITTED
id  = 18192 amount = 160 nameType = POSITIVE
id  = 18192 amount = 30 nameType = DRAFT
id  = 18192 amount = 873 nameType = SUBMITTED
id  = 18237 amount = 390 nameType = POSITIVE
id  = 18237 amount = 60 nameType = DRAFT
id  = 18237 amount = 2731 nameType = SUBMITTED
```

I want to transform this list to a `map` with this form, the key is the `id` and the value is a `list` of objects :

```java
Map<Integer,List<ItemDetails>> mapTest= new HashMap<Integer,List<ItemDetails>>();
```

```
[18237 , [amount = 390 ,nameType = POSITIVE],[amount = 60 nameType = DRAFT], [amount = 2731 nameType = SUBMITTED]], ...
```

I tried with different ways but always I had repeated elements:

```java
List<Integer> ids2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(Item item: resultBl) {
  ids.add(item.getId());
}

ids2 =ids.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
Map<Integer,List<ItemDetails>>  mapTest= new HashMap<Integer,List<ItemDetails>>();
List<ItemDetails> itemDetailsList = new ArrayList<ItemDetails>();
for(Integer s:ids2) {
    for(Item i : resultBl) {
      if(s.equals(i.getId())) {
         ItemDetails it =new ItemDetails();
         it.setAmount(i.getAmount());
         it.setNameType(i.getNameType()) ;
         itemDetailsList .add(it);
      }
    }
    mapTest.put(s, itemDetailsList);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collectors.groupingBy` with `Collectors.mapping` for `downstream` should work:

```
Map<Integer, List<ItemDetails>> result = resultBl.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getId, Collectors.mapping(ItemDetails::new, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: I had this error : The method mapping(Function<? super T,? extends U>, Collector<? super U,A,R>) in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments (ItemDetails::new, Collector<Object,capture#3-of ?,List<Object>>)

Comment: `ItemDetails` should have `ItemDetail(Item item)` constructor. Otherwise you should implement mapper function instead of using `ItemDetails::new`

Answer (score 0):

I would use streams and `groupingBy` to do this.

When you have a list of your items `resultBl` all you have to do is

```
Map<Integer, List<Item>> resultMap = resultBl.stream().collect(groupingBy(Item::getId, toList()));
```

imports:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
```

This will group your items by the `id` parameter.

Comment: Good, but this misses the fact that the values of the map should be a list of `ItemDetails`, not of `Item`.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to add a constructor to `ItemDetails` accepting an `Item` object:

```java
public class ItemDetails {

    // properties, getters and setters

    public ItemDetails(Item item) {
        this.amount = item.getAmount();
        this.nameType = item.getNameType();
    }

}
```

And then use the following Java 8 features:

```java
Map<Integer, List<ItemDetails>> itemsPerId = 
  itemsList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getId, Collectors.mapping(ItemDetails::new, Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Map<Integer,List<Item>>  map = resultBL.stream(Collectors.toMap(Item::getId, Function.identity()));
```

It is Lambda. Java version >= 8

Comment: This doesn't look right. `List.stream()` doesn't accept parameters. Looks like you forgot a `collect`.

Comment: Also, the values of the map should be a list of `ItemDetails`, not of `Item`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but It didn't work